# Oscillation of Free End of String (Waves)

Tags: waves, string, oscillators

Suppose a wave pulse is produced in a string clamped at one end, and the other end is loose(tied with a massless ring which can move along a vertical rod, there's no friction). Now, I have searched everywhere on internet, they say the net restoring force on free end of string is zero, therefore the slope is zero, hence no component of tension pulling it. My doubt here is that, if it doesn't have restoring force , then how does it even oscillate? I think restoring force towards mean position is a necessary condition for oscillation. Consider the string to be light. No damping is to be considered.
for reference:
https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/html/wave-on-a-string/latest/wave-on-a-string_en.html
Here is the link of an animation, adjust the settings to free end, wave pulse, no damping and slow motion. You would see that when the wave is at the end , the two particles (green and red) are always horizontal, suggesting that the slope is zero.

Comment: I have used the words "free " and "loose" interchangeably. I hope there is no problem regarding that.

Comment: There is a force on the loose end of the string at most times, being the tension from the next infinitesimal section of the string.  But there is a net zero force at /some/ times, since the velocity of the string changes sign (nil acceleration where the sign changes).

Comment: @Tony i don't really think that because there was one question which i was doing and it said,"write the slope of loose end as function of time". The answer was "zero". if slope is zero, tension is always horizontal hence no vertical pulling.
Also, you could see that in the animation ig

Comment: Okay, but that loose end is moving, and the movement is initially up, then down, then up, and so on.  So its velocity is changing sign, so there is acceleration.  If the string has mass (find me a real one that doesn't!) then there is also force.

Comment: @Tony i guess that's what the whole question is about, there is force, (or there isn't, i don't know, i prefer to be all blank) , but that force isn't tension, at least that's what i found on surfing the internet. I said "light" string so that you don't consider the effect of gravity.

Comment: This might help you -- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/219282/vibrating-string-free-end-boundary-condition.  I prefer the second answer (not the one accepted).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150706/discussion-between-pinkaura-and-tony).

Comment: Wire dynamics depend on the pre-stress (tension), especially the displacement in the transversal direction: with no pre-tension, a wire has no transverse (shear and bending) stiffness, and thus no restoring force

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me try an answer and hopefully someone can come in with something more authoritative if it is lacking...

### String is made up of tiny sections

The common introductory treatment of waves on a string assumes that the string is made up of lots of tiny sections that are joined together.  Let's assume the string is initially parallel to the floor along its whole length.

### Sections not at and end

For any section that is not at an end of the string, there is tension due to the section on the left and tension due to the section on the right. The magnitude of the tension is assumed to be nearly the same at each end of the section, especially as the section gets smaller, but small differences result in a non-zero *net* force and make the section bend upwards or downwards.

Now to get the most accurate approximation we make the segments smaller; approaching zero size.  As the section becomes smaller and smaller the mass of the section becomes negligible and so any *net* tension force must be small to prevent unphysical acceleration (since $F=ma$).  Luckily, as the section becomes smaller the tensions at each end are also becoming more and more equal, so the net force is indeed getting smaller.

### Sections at a loose end (constrained to move only up and down)

A section at a loose end is constrained to move only up and down (e.g. by a ring on a frictionless rod).  If we assume that the constraint is friction-free, then at a loose end the section experiences tension in the vertical direction from only one neighbouring section (the other end is free to move vertically without constraint).  As the section becomes smaller and smaller its mass becomes negligible but the net force doesn't decrease.  So either the vertical component of the single tension force must be negligible or the acceleration of the segment in the vertical direction becomes unphysical.  As the size of the section approaches zero the mass also approaches zero and the vertical component of the tension must also approach zero to avoid infinite vertical acceleration.

### Un-real world solution

As the loose segment becomes infinitesimally small the  vertical component of the single tension force must go to *zero in the limit*, to avoid unphysical acceleration.  So we impose this as a condition.  We don't have to actually get to zero; it's enough that the vertical component of the single force is as small as the *net* force on the neighbouring infinitesimal section (recall that the latter has two offsetting forces and the net force gets really tiny as the section gets really tiny).  The nature of a limit is that we don't have to actually get to zero, just arbitrarily close.

If the vertical component of the single tension force is approaching zero in the limit then the section doesn't bend (it's flat) and so the gradient at the very end of the string is zero.

### Real world

In the real world the "loose" end is constrained to move only up and down and the constraining object, such as a vertical string or rod, is not frictionless.  The friction counteracts the single tension force.  We need not have a "flat" end.

Here are some videos of waves on physical "strings" with a free end:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZxIlyptT1FY
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WUwkyfI_oKU

Comment: Really cool the last video, that is showing waves on the transversal direction of the wire using torsion

Comment: i seem to put the things together, some doubts:
1."More specifically, the component of the single tension in the vertical direction must be negligible". Why not horizontal? 2."We don't have to actually get to zero; it's enough that the vertical component of the single force is as small as the net force on the neighbouring infinitesimal section " Suppose the net force on the neighbouring particle is dT , so at the end, string is oriented such that there is at least dT restoring force, right?

Comment: 1. In the horizontal direction the constraining object counterbalances the tension.   2. Yes, but the net force dT gets infinitesimal as the section size approaches zero, so the limit can still be zero (and the derivative is a limit).

Comment: @Tony oh thanks, sorry to keep you bothering ,1. "In the horizontal direction the constraining object counterbalances the tension", so what do you think how it's balanced when the string end is free? (or is there a tension at all?)
2. Yes thanks a lot, i am now clear with it

Comment: Re your follow-up on 1): It's not genuinely free.  It is constrained to only move in the vertical direction.  If it were genuinely free then it would be pulled horizontally (unless the horizontal component of tension were assumed to be zero).

Comment: @Tony hmm, so the cases that we take of free end are wrong?
For example , here: https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/html/wave-on-a-string/latest/wave-on-a-string_en.html

Comment: If I look at that site and choose "loose end" there appears to be a ring around a rod at the loose end (assumed frictionless).  I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: @Tony choose free end or no end
Anyway, my main doubt is cleared i guess, so would think about it later; thanks

Comment: Okay.  I don't see a "free end" option.  I think perhaps "No end" just means it goes on forever.  i.e. infinite length string (try setting damping to None).  I have changed my answer slightly to make it clear that only the vertical component is being considered (horizontal tension is allowed).  Perhaps we can leave it there?

Comment: just one last thing, "I have changed my answer slightly to make it clear that only the vertical component is being considered (horizontal tension is allowed). Perhaps we can leave it there?", there is horizontal tension but it is balanced by the ring constraint, right? Thank you for your patience

Comment: "There is horizontal tension but it is balanced by the ring constraint, right?".  Yes.